# Getting the features of HTC Sense in vanilla Android?

Tags: htc-sense, vanilla-android

I've had an HTC Desire for a year or so and am due an upgrade. I'm weighing my options and I'm fairly sure I'm going to go with the Galaxy Nexus.

Thing is I've gotten used to HTC Sense and all the extra features it offers over vanill Android. What apps/widgets can I get to add the functionality that I lose by not having Sense?

Also what will I lose by not having sense?

Comment: What Sense feature sin detail do you like most? Add them to your question and we will see if there is an non-HTC alternative...

Comment: I've never had a stock Android phone so I don't know which features are sense only... That is half the problem, the only flavour of Android I've spent any time with has been an HTC sense phone, as fat as I'm concerned HTC sense might as well be Android.

Comment: For testing a Stock Android you can use the Android Emulator that is part of the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). Then you will see and feel the massive difference.

Answer (score 2):

You could replicate many Sense features with 3rd-party apps such as Launcher replacements, dialer/contact apps, various widgets, etc.  However, you will likely lose the deep system integration of such apps.  You will also most definitely lose the integration with the [HTC Sense](https://www.htcsense.com) site.

Comment: The Desire doesn't integrate with the HTC Sense site so I won't miss that... Although I kinda wish I did have those features...